# How to execute a command in tmux and detach using a single line command?

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen, terminal-multiplexer

How can I get tmux to execute a command and then detach (That is, automatically in a single line without further input beyond initially starting the session)?

I don't know to write sophisticated scripts. But I used to do this in screen with a command like:

`screen -S torrent -d -m qbittorrent-nox`

But I have been reading that tmux is better and I would like to switch. But I couldn't figure out how to achieve what the above command does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual:

> **new-session** [-AdDEPX] [-c start-directory] [-e environment] [-f flags]
> [-F format] [-n window-name] [-s session-name] [-t group-name] [-x width]
> [-y height] [shell-command]
> (alias: new)
> Create a new session with name session-name.
> **The new session is attached to the current terminal unless -d is
> given.** window-name and shell-command are the name of and shell command
> to execute in the initial window.

You can replace the *screen* command with (naming the session for easy management as suggested by @cas):

```
tmux new-session -d -s torrent qbittorrent-nox
```

It will create a detached session named *torrent* (rather than a number) with `qbittorrent-nox` running inside. When the command ends, so will the session.

---

You can then attach to this specific session (in case there are multiple created) with:

```
tmux attach-session -t torrent
```

Or if already having a *tmux* client attached to an other session, you can swith to this one instead with:

```
tmux switch-client -t torrent
```

(or simply navigate with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>(</kbd>, <kbd>)</kbd>).

Comment: +1.  Also, it's worthwhile specifying a session name with `-s` so you can easily attach to it (or add another window, or whatever, in that session) **by name**, rather than having to figure out what it is with `tmux ls`.    e.g. `tmux new-session -s qbt -d qbittorrent-nox`.   optionally name the window too with `-n`.